# Getting response as Json from sAuth URL in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I am having a requirement where I need to get user information by passing a unique accesstoken and retrieve the response which is in-turn returned by the URL in JSON format.

My problem is when i'm passing the access token directly to the URL  and browse in the browser like this [https://opsauth-dot-cfsauth-preview.appspot.com/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + accesstoken + "&callback=?](https://opsauth-dot-cfsauth-preview.appspot.com/v1/userinfo?access_token=%22%20%20%20accesstoken%20%20%20%22&callback=?), i'm seeing the json response, but when I'm trying to pass the URL and get response as Json in my Asp.Net MVC application. i'm getting error like "Unable to connect to remote server".

I'm using the following code in my Asp.Net application to fetch the json response:

```
string url = "https://opsauth-dot-cfsauth-preview.appspot.com/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + accesstoken + "&callback=?";
  using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
  {       
   var json  = wc.DownloadString(url);
  }
```

In the above code, I'm passing my unique access token variable instead of `" + accesstoken + "`.

I'm getting the error in `wc.DownloadString(url)`. Not sure what I'm missing or whether the code which is used for getting the json response is correct or not. Can anybody please help/provide your suggestions on how to get the response in Json in .Net MVC?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was there was an issue in my network it seems. Now it is working fine. I'm able to get the response now as Json in my .Net application. The issue was that it was working in the internet connection and able to get Json response in application whereas  throwing error in my office network. Not sure why was that behavior. Anyways Thanks @FrankerZ for your time to extend help and sorry for the trouble.